# An assembly with the same identity 'XXX' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a MVC web application that I publish to our UAT server with msbuild command line. It is hosted on a windows 2016 server, IIS 10.

Sometimes, **not always**, I have a the following error when I try to start up the website:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
>
> Source Error:
>   [No relevant source lines]
>   Source File:    Line: 0
>   Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv> 
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /R:
>
> ...
>
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4a1a5bcc\84ed54d3\assembly\dl3\ab6a43c3\00602620_2137d201\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /R:
>
> ...
>
> "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.ReaderWriter\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /R:
>
> ...
>
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4a1a5bcc\84ed54d3\App_Web_home.cshtml.65a2d1ee.ef3qnjdl.1.cs"
>   Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1586.0
>
> for C# 5
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
>
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4a1a5bcc\84ed54d3\assembly\dl3\ab6a43c3\00602620_2137d201\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.DLL: error CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.ReaderWriter\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0

I have tried to look for references, but I can see it only once in the web.config.

Also, the error usually goes away after I run an iisreset or restart the web server.
My fear is this could happen on the live server too if we release it.

I would appreciate any help to point me to the right direction to fix this.

**UPDATE:**

I have checked all the references in the whole project. All I can find is.

**Web.config:**

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.5" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50">
        <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" />
            <add assembly="System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

and **Packages.config:**

```
<package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have removed the "add assembly" from the web.config as suggested by Péter Csajtai. 
Since then it is working fine (probably it is not used anywhere).

I have tried to remove the other assemblies, but those are used, so I would need multiple [redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions). On the other hand it is working, so I am reluctant a bit to "fix it". I have added a redirect to see if it would work, but without an error it is hard to tell if it is doing the right thing.

Also found [this](https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/08/26/troubleshooting-nuget-references.aspx) that could be useful for other's for troubleshooting in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the output states, your projects are referencing the `System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll` from two different places:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4a1a5bcc\84ed54d3\assembly\dl3\ab6a43c3\00602620_2137d201\

And from the GAC:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.ReaderWriter\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\

You should check all your references to that dll and unify the reference paths where they are different.

Comment: I have already checked all the references in the whole project. All I can find is....
(I have added the config parts to the ticket above, I couldn't figure out the formatting here.)

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `<assemblies>` part from your web.config? It seems to me it adds the `4.0.0.0` version but you also referencing the `4.3.0` from nuget.

Comment: I have plenty references that can be found both in the web.config and the packages.config. Should I try to remove all of them from the web.config?

Comment: You should unify them yes, however for now i think you should only focus to the problematic `System.Xml.ReaderWriter`, when that becomes ok, then you can continue the same process with the remaining. I would also recommend to try [assemblyBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) redirections in your web.config for those assemblies which has version mismatches.

Comment: I have removed the "add assembly" from the web.config. Since then it is working fine (probably it is not used anywhere). Added a few redirects too, but it is hard to tell if it fixes anything as there are no errors to start with. (updated the question above, thanks)

Comment: I had a near identical problem, except the DLL was System.Runtime.DLL. After removing the specific "add assembly" from the web.config it worked.