# Metadata file System.dll could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I'm getting the following error when trying to access Sitecore backend while upgrading to 9.3:

```
Metadata file 'C:\...\bin\System.dll' could not be found
```

I checked the GAC and it's in there. 
When I try to copy the dll to the bin folder (from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089), I get the following error:

```
An assembly with the same identity 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
```

I already tried repairing my .NET framework installation and cleaning and rebuilding/republishing also didn't help.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you might have imported the corresponding assembly twice.

Check whether there is **system.dll** under **bin** folder, if you find it, remove it.

I am also pasting the article from the asp.net forums from which, I got the idea: [An assembly has already been imported](https://forums.asp.net/t/1811055.aspx?CS1703%20An%20assembly%20with%20the%20same%20identity%20mscorlib%20Version%204%200%200%200%20Culture%20neutral%20PublicKeyToken%20b77a5c561934e089%20has%20already%20been%20imported%20Try%20removing%20one%20of%20the%20duplicate%20references%20)

Comment: There's no System.dll in the bin folder. I've also checked a vanilla Sitecore 9.3 installation, which also doesn't contain a System.dll in its bin folder.

Comment: Maybe try a whole solution search for system.dll, I bet it will be referenced from 2 or more projects.

Also check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211315/an-assembly-with-the-same-identity-xxx-has-already-been-imported-try-removing

Comment: Yeah, already tried that. Problem is System.dll itself isn't referenced anywhere. I appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: I am going to search a bit more then, if I find something i'll keep you posted.

Comment: is there any news on that?